# How to jump back to the first character in *nix command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, keyboard-shortcuts, cursor

When writing a long command in the *nix command line and having to go back to the first character, in order to add something at the beginning (for instance a `nohup`, when you realize the process will be a long one, or a `sudo`, when you realize you need root permissions) it can take a long time for the cursor to make its way back to the first character...

Is there a short cut that allows you to jump straight there?

I'm using a mac, so <kbd>Home</kbd> is not an option

Comment: If you're on an Apple laptop, Fn + Left/Right are equivalent to Home/End. (And relatedly, Fn + Up/Down are PageUp/Down.)

Comment: To those reading this question, this is in effect asking about the shell, more specifically command line editing in the shell. The Ctrl-A answer before is bash (most likely) with Emacs style editing, the default.

Comment: An alternative if you just need to add `sudo` is to type `sudo !!`. The `!!` gets replaced with the previous command.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> should work. <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> corresponds to the end of the command line.

Comment: Great! This works perfectly also on mac!

Comment: This also applies in many code editors.

Comment: @clami219: It actually works in most text contexts in OSX. Emacs bindings is a wonderful thing...

Comment: Thank you, it works on Linux as well.

Answer (score 10):

This depends on the shell in question.

Some shells (like AT&T ksh88) offer virtually no input line editing.

In shells implementing `vi` mode editing (you may have to enable this with `set -o vi`), this is done by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> (to switch from insert mode) followed by <kbd>0</kbd> to jump to the beginning of line or <kbd>$</kbd> to jump to the end of line. Then re-enter insert mode either by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> – the cursor will stay where it is – or <kbd>a</kbd> – the cursor will move one to the right to append text.

`vi` mode editing has recently been mandated by the POSIX standard.

The *much more common* `emacs` mode editing (thank gods, it has nothing to do with the Emacs editor-slash-operating-system) uses <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> to jump to the beginning of the line and <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd> to jump to the end of the line. This mode requires you to run `set -o emacs` on many shells (most prominently AT&T ksh93) but is enabled by default in [mksh](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/mksh) and GNU bash.

Most modern shells support both `emacs` and `vi` modes. (Both these modes require a tty to work.)

In many shells, you can customise keybindings; usually for the `emacs` mode, although some shells also permit customising the keybinding for the `vi` mode. If you have a key you'd rather have this bound to, you first need to figure out the key sequences it produces (for example, on my system, <kbd>Alt-CursorLeft</kbd> produces <kbd>Esc+[+1+;+3+D</kbd> (`^[[1;3D`; `^X` is <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> and `^[` is <kbd>Esc</kbd>), so I can type something like

```
bind '^[[1;3D=beginning-of-line'
bind '"\e[1;3D":beginning-of-line'
```

and will have this keybinding changed, depending on the shell. You can usually persist them in either the startup file (`~/.mkshrc`, `~/.kshrc`) or, for GNU bash, in `~/.inputrc`. Note that not all shells support bindind all keys in all versions.

You can usually find out what chars a key generates by just running `cat` on the shell, typing the key and watching. Then press `^C` (<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>) to abort `cat`.

Comment: I like to use ^D, the Unix end-line character, to end cat. In my mind, it's ^D because the text stream is "done".

Comment: @AaronHall: that will not work if there's already something on the line. Plus, we want to abort it, not end it ;-) But yes, in the normal case you're right. But this is a special case.

Comment: The terminal may do line editing as well.

Comment: @mirabilos To send an EOF without a newline, simply do ^D^D (i.e. press D twice).

Comment: @Potatoswatter yes (fun, I didn't know that myself), but I specifically want to abort here. When sending `^D^D` I still get “the junk” echoed…

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Home key? I use MobXterm to connect to linux box and use both Home and End key on the keyboard to go to first or last char of the command.

Comment: You are right! I had to specify that I'm using a mac...

Answer (score 2):

If you've switched to `vi` mode, using `set -o vi`, you can hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and either <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>A</kbd> to enter text at the start or the end of the line. Or if you're just looking to move the cursor, it's <kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>$</kbd>.

Comment: vi mode of what shell?

Answer (score 2):

In emacs mode (switched by: `set -o emacs`) it's by pressing:

- <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>
- <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc+b</kbd> and <kbd>Esc+f</kbd> (moves the cursor backward and forward of the current word )

In vi mode (switched by: `set -o vi`) when in command mode (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) it's by pressing:

- <kbd>0</kbd>/<kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>$</kbd> (it'll stay in command mode)
- <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> (it'll switch to edit mode)

See also:

- [Advanced Shell Topics: Command line movement and editing](http://suso.suso.org/docs/adv_shell/movement.phtml)